# Instagram search hashtag with a period in it?

Tags: c#, instagram, urlencode

I'm using instagram api to search posts containing certain hashtags. I need to find a hashtag like "abc.com". My request url becomes
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/**abc.com**/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
which gives 404.
I've tried replacing . with %2E but it is not working. Any suggestion?

I'm using  C# to send the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahsen Instagram tags do not contain "." in them. If you try to put it it breaks the tag to part that comes before it.

e.g. #abc.com - the tag will be #abc only

How ever you can use "_" in tags.

I think this is the reason you are getting 404.